In Stargate: Universe why didn't the Nakai alter Dr. Rush as they did Chloe?
In Stargate: Universe the Nakai capture Dr. Rush first and Chloe later.  They had Dr. Rush for a lot longer than they had Chloe before the two are rescued (or let go?).  But, despite Dr. Rush being in their custody a lot longer than Chloe, it is Chloe they modify in order to spy on or sabotage the Destiny crew, while Rush only gets a tracker implanted in his chest, we later learn  --- and how do the Nakai know that Dr. Rush would return to Destiny and that therefore they could implant a device on him to track Destiny?
My question: if the Nakai knew Dr. Rush would return to Destiny --- and that is why they implanted the tracking device on him --- why didn't they modify him like they modified Chloe?

Why is this question opinion-based?  It may not have an in-universe answer, but not being answerable is not the same as being opinion-based.

It might have been flagged that way because the answers most likely given or going to be opinion based...
